# How to use the context functions with the return value from mysqli_init in PHP mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have some PHP code that uses mysqli_init()
I would like to set only VERIFY_PEER_NAME to false and not PEER_VERIFY.

The flag MYSQLI_OPT_DO_NOT_VERIFY_CERTIFICATE passed to mysqli_real_connect() sets both to false if I ask it to, plus modified ALLOW_SELF_SIGNED.

The mysqli C code uses the context functions to set the OPENSSL/PHP based on what is passed to mysqli_real_connect.  If the C code can do it why can't I do it in my PHP code.  Both the C code and the PHP context functions require a resource or context.
How do I convert the mysqli object return by mysqli_init() to a resource/context that the PHP context functions can handle.  There doesn't appear to be context object within the mysqli object.

I am fine with modifying mysqli.php code, but I would rather not modify the C code for mysqli.so.

I have attempted to post a feature request on the PHP.net site, but keep running into problems.  The latest was invalid captcha when the submit form doesn't even have a captcha field.  Using Chrome, perhaps I should try Edge, or Firefox.

Comment: Is this what you are talking about? https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/8769

Comment: Yes, that would be the same thing.  That would be the feature request I am looking for. for PHP mysqli.  I think that might be for the mysql command line.